# Xcode and SPM Libraries

Tags: xcode, swift, vim, swift-package-manager

I want to code my Project with the Swift Package Manager. The only possible way to get code-completion is through Xcode AFAIK. All other attempts to get code-completion in Vim failed for me.

Setup of my Swift package:

```
$ mkdir SwiftProject
$ cd SwiftProject

$ swift package init --type executable
```

This step generates the standard package structure with `Package.swift`, Source folder containing `main.swift` and so on.

```
$ swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

The last step generates `SwiftProject.xcodeproj` with all settings for building the swift package from Xcode.

Everything works so far, until dependencies are added through `Package.swift`.

My current `Package.swift`:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftProject",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/czechboy0/Socks.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 7)
    ]
)
```

Now when I `import SocksCore` in my `main.swift` and work with it, compiling it through CLI `swift build` works fine and it runs. But my Xcode-Project doesn't compile, because it can't find the SocksCore module. I think I need to import the `.dylib`-Files, so Xcode can build the project.

To my Problem now: How do I generate those dynamic libraries with the SPM? I don't find a way to do this. Every tutorial about using SPM with Xcode has got this `.dylib` or static libraries `.a`, but this tutorials are build with an older development snapshot version than mine. I build with `DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-06-a`. I can't find a way to build them with my snapshot. Is this not possible anymore? Or what am I doing wrong at this point?

Or is there another way working with SPM and Xcode? Would be nice if I could find a solution to start my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently need to regenerate the Xcode project manually whenever you make a change to the structure of the package. That includes adding new dependencies, but also any time you add a new source file.

Comment: Oh my...well, now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify/simplify Daniel's Dunbar answer,
after every

```
swift package update
```

u should generate xcodeproj again:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```